# What causes Coup de Grace?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

What causes Coup de Grace in Dragon Quest 9?

Answer (score 8):

This link explains what helps to improve the trigger of the Coup de Grâce (see Trigger table)

[DragonQuest Wiki](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Coup_de_Gr%C3%A2ce)

The frequency of a Coup de Grâce occurring is amplified by the following conditions:

```
Critical fan equipped   +6%
Overcritical fan equipped   +7%
Hypercritical fan equipped  +8%
Dire critical fan equipped  +10%
Combat action medal     +3%
Martial artist, Ranger, or Luminary     +3%
1 other party member primed     +0.8%
2 other party members primed    +10%
3 other party members primed    +36%
10% damage taken    +0.75%
20% damage taken    +1.5%
30% damage taken    +3%
40% damage taken    +6%
50% damage taken    +12%
60% damage taken    +24%
70% damage taken    +48%
80% damage taken    +95%
```

Comment: In case that link ever goes away, it would be better if this answer included the content of that link.

Comment: I believe you have to be at least level 10 to be able to use a Coup de Grâce on a character.

Comment: What does "party member primed" mean?

Comment: @JānisElmeris I assume it means "a party member that is ready to use a coup de grace"

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on what you're fighting. If it's any easy kill monster, your chances are really low, but if you're fighting a major boss (such as Corvus) your chances are increased.

Answer (score 0):

Your coup de grace depends on your vocation

Warrior - Makes a attack that will always be a critical hit
Martial Artist - Terroises enimies that cannot be resisted , and tenison of the user goes up to 5
Preist - Heals all allies in one go ( its like multiheal or omniheal for free but the HP recovery is dictated only by the user's magical mending)
Ministrel - increases chance of doding and counterattacks ( its like back atcha ( its a sheild skill learnt at skill point 88 ) but with increased chance)
Mage - All MP costs for speels are reduced to 0 for a few turn (useful for doing powerful high level spells)
Theif- 100% chance of item drop on the enemy used on , does not guranantee bosses though.

Paladin - Makes use invincible and all enemies attck the user rendering ut useless.
Ranger - incread resistence to breath atttacks , attack and defence by 1 level
Gladiator - raises Tension of user to 50 or 100
Arenemantalist - Multiplies Xp drop ranging from ×1.1 to ×1.9
Sage - Restores all or nearly all MP depending on the users stats
Luminary - Same as Martial artist but the enemies boogie.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, BIG Serious Damage is a high chance to use Coup De Grace, use them well or wait for other party has Coup de Garce as well. If you wanna beat Corvus again...be careful very very sometimes used Magic Burst. He high level Sage can learn that. Defend yourself randomly. All your parties are primed Coup De Grace very naturally. Oh by the way, wanna steal something? Sure! Bring theif with you and find handsome crabs! (I'm just collecting resurock for example) If crab use critical attack to their. Prime to coup de grace hi chance! (find handsome crab has same-wise level your thief character)